# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(17n)!}{(n!)^{17}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(17n)!}{(n!)^{17}}}$$

I know that if we can show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=L$

So we have to look at  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{[17(n+1)]!}{[(n+1)!]^{17}}}}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{(17n)!}{(n!)^{17}}}}$$

I managed to continue to:$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)[17n]!}{(n+1)^{17}[(n!)]^{17}}}}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{(17n)!}{(n!)^{17}}}}$$

So it is of the form:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)a}{(n+1)^{17}b}}}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{a}{b}}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)^{17}}}\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{a}{b}}}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{a}{b}}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)^{17}}}\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{a}{b}}}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{a}{b}}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)^{17}}}\sqrt[n(n+1)]{\frac{a}{b}}}$$

But I can see how to proceed

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: ... which will give an answer of $827240261886336764177$

Comment: I think your way will work. Only you chose $a_n$ as what's under the n-root, but when you test $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$  you still kept the n-root. The purpose of this test is you get rid of the root :)

Comment: And another mistake is that $(17(n+1))! \neq (n+1)\cdot  (17n)!$.

Comment: @Atticus I get $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{17(n+1)}{(n+1)^{17}}}=0$

Comment: @newhere, You should get $(17n+1)(17n+2)\cdot \ldots \cdot (17n+17)$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote: $ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{[17(n+1)]!}{[(n+1)!]^{17}}}}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{(17n)!}{(n!)^{17}}}}.$

But this is not true, since $a_n= \frac{(17n)!}{(n!)^{17}}$.

With this you should get (the computations are your turn):

$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{17n+1}{n+1} \cdot \frac{17n+2}{n+1} \cdot .... \cdot \frac{17n+17}{n+1}.$

Thus $ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to 17^{17}$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{[17(n+1)]!}{[(n+1)!]^{17}}*\frac{(n!)^{17}}{(17n)!}=\frac{17(n+1)}{(n+1)^{17}}$

Comment: @newhere No, $\frac{[17(n+1)]!}{(17n)!}=\frac{[17n+17]!}{(17n)!}$ is a product of $17$ consecutive values.

Comment: @J.G. Ok so from $\frac{[17(n+1)]!}{[(n+1)!]^{17}}*\frac{(n!)^17}{((17n)!}$ we get $\frac{[17(n+1)]!}{(n+1)^{17}}*\frac{1}{(17n)!}$ ?